# how to compare item with all other items using forEach in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I need for a given list of words to determine whether it contains anagrams.
For example:

```
hasAnagrams(listOf("restful", "elvis", "fluster")) -> true
hasAnagrams(listOf("restful", "elvis", "real")) -> false
```

My code:

```
fun hasAnagrams(words: List<String>): Boolean =
words.map { it.split(" ") }.forEach { item -> return item.containsAll(item) }
```

My code returns a unit and I do not know how to return a boolean, making the code short, concise and idiomatically correct. Also, I do not know whether it is worth using `.forEach` or there is a more correct method for this action. And did I write this line correctly `item -> return item.containsAll(item)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In words.map you split each of given sentence into list of words and then, for each of this list, you check if all elements in this list is in this list, which is always true. 
There is no sense in using foreach in this example. It returns Unit, which sth like void in java.

Maybe you wanted sth like this?

```
fun hasAnagrams(words: List<String>): Boolean = words
    .map { it.split("").sorted() } // split given words into list of chars and sort
    .distinct() // get only unique lists
    .size != words.size // check if number of unique lists is equal to number of words in input list
```